# ReactJS: PureRenderMixin addon footnote - contradiction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

from the documentation here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html

The footnote is saying that you should use `forceUpdate()` if the structure of complexe data (deep data structure) is changed.

From the definition of a pure : `it renders the same result given the same props and state`.

I'm thinking more and more that this is a contradiction because if the data structure changes, it means that you are giving new props/state. Thus the component is not "pure" anymore.

In my opinion, if you change the props or state that is passed to the component you can either:

```
use forceUpdate().
remove PureRenderMixin from the mixins.
```

Thus, under the hood... you are transforming a component that is pure to a "non-pure" component. So removing PureRenderMixin should be the only option available.

Am I right ? Or a Pure component means that the component is "cached" and reused when giving the same props ?

Sorry but I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: By definition, a component whose state can be modified can't be pure, because state is stored on the object, not passed in as arguments. In other words, you can feed it the same arguments, and it may produce a different result depending on whether or not the state has changed.

Answer (score 3):

`PureRenderMixin` is used to give React a way of knowing that it shouldn't call your `render` method unnecessarily. For example, if your `render` method is complex enough, it can give you a performance boost if your component isn't being re-rendered with the same props/state.

But, like it's said in the documentation, `PureRenderMixin` does not compare deeply nested data structures, so it might not call your `render` function, when it should have, because some nested structure actually changed.

In these cases, it's better to not use `PureRenderMixin` and use `shouldComponentUpdate` and perform you own comparison logic.

Also, from the docs, you [should avoid using `forceUpdate`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html).

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment. Actually, I got it just after by playing with it. In some scenario you want to update even if it's a PureRenderMixin and specially when using object.

Answer (score 0):

The absence of side effect is an important aspect of the mixin because it enables the logic of not rendering the component twice given the same state.

That shouldn't be a satisfying answer because, as you pointed out, nested changes won't be caught by the shallow checking... Unless your data structure are immutable!

I strongly recommend watching [Lee Byron's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7IdS-PbEgI&list=PLb0IAmt7-GS1cbw4qonlQztYV1TAW0sCr&index=13) on immutable data structures which explains how immutable data improves the performance of your application by avoiding a whole class of problems.

Essentially, a smart library like immutable.js will share common state between two snapshots of an immutable object. 
Therefore shallow equality becomes a proof of the underlying data not being changed.

Comment: This still seems wrong.A shallow compare shouldn't produce false negatives, it should return true and render if two nested objects are reference unequal. Maybe this is why this exists? https://github.com/jurassix/react-immutable-render-mixin

Comment: Interesting code, thanks for sharing. A shallow comparison will return a false positive if you modify a field inside a model without changing the pointer to the model itself. It happens frequently.

Comment: @JoeWood A shallow compare will only produce false negatives on mutable object structures (such as ordinary JS objects and arrays).

If the data structure you're comparing is immutable, a shallow equality comparison is all that is required.